# Why do atomic operations like fetch-and-add return the old value of the variable being changed?

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, atomic

I am trying to learn and get better at understanding multithreading, but I got hung up on the behavior of atomic functions like fetch-and-add. In the specific case of fetch-and-add, it is my understanding that a value (let's say x which currently equals 5) is added to by an increment value (let's say 3), the resulting sum (8) is written to x's place in memory, yet the old value (5) is returned.

There are several other such functions in different places (like OpenGL's atomic functions, Java's AtomicIntegers, and many more areas) that behave like this. But what I don't understand is why a place in code would want to write to memory and yet still return the value that it wanted to modify in the first place. Can anyone help shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Sergey's answer...

I look at fetch-and-add to be something similar to a semaphore; except the fetch-and-add call makes everything an atomic operation.  Here is an example of an algorithm that shows the use of the original value: http://research.omicsgroup.org/index.php/Ticket_lock

Comment: This was an incredibly helpful article to read. Thank you, Sergey, and Dimitar so much for the help and examples!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is very simple. The nature of atomic functions is that they modify (increment in this case) the actual value **at the time of execution** which might be different from the value as your code knew it.

example:

```
x = 5; // x is global
y = atomically_increment(x);
// what is y?
```

Now, if x happened to be changed from 5 to 6 right before increment actually took place, y would be equal to 6, and x to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch-and-add instructions or operations (like x86's `XADD`) save you from the trouble of doing a CAS loop and providing an expected initial value.

However this also means that in your code, after the fetch-and-add succeeds, you don't know to what value was your increment added and under heavy contention, reading the value just before fetch-and-adding to it could still be far away from the truth. That's why returning the old or new value as the result of the atomic fetch-and-add is very useful.

As an example, [Aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/Aeron) uses the value returned by fetch-and-add in order to determine whether it should rotate its buffer (see https://youtu.be/eKVpea51tvo?t=31m54s).